# Laravel Vue.js Events not firing

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to use only Single File Components with Laravel. The components are mounted but events do not fire. Inside `ExampleComponent` I have a button `@click="test"` that does not fire.

It worked previously when I directly used the `ExampleComponent` within the blade template but after incorporating an `App.vue` component the events stopped.

**Blade Template**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}""></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'
import App from './components/App.vue'

Vue.use(Buefy)
Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue'));


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ExampleComponent/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ExampleComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

**ExampleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div style="background-color: #f7faff">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <button @click="test">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log("TEST")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: why are using `id="app"` also in `app.vue` `<div id="app">
    <ExampleComponent/>`?

Comment: That's how Vue.js does it in their demo app. https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9 @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: it's not need try to remove and it could generate some issues because in this case you have two elements with the same id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Blade Template seems to have conflicting Javascript files that are loaded.

```
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}""></script>
```

Should be the **only** script you are loading. That way, Laravel [Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) can always compile the latest changes to your `app.js` file. See if that helps, because your `.vue` and `.js` files look wired up correctly.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, only to find that I had made an unnecessary import in the app.js